# Cant read xlsx file using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

i want to read xlsx file and write back some data to the file like below :

```
try {
 $reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();        
 $spreadsheet = $reader->load('CatagoryEng.xlsx');
 dd($spreadsheet);
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
 dd($ex);
}
```

the above code works fine in local but in server it gives the below exception

```
ErrorException {#1444 ▼
  #message: "Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/home/ar../vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx/Styles.php"
  #line: 133
  #severity: E_NOTICE
  trace: {▶}
}
```

other information :

- the some package `"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.4"` used both in local and server.
- php version is  `"php": "^7.1.3"`
- laravel version is `"laravel/framework": "5.6.*"`

Comment: So which line is failing exactly? Does `$reader` fail or maybe `$spreadsheet`? What the heck is `dd()`?

Comment: `dd()` - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd. I've always heard it referred to as, "dump 'n die".

Comment: Are you PHP and Laravel versions the same on both servers?

Comment: Great, so is `$reader` failing or is it `$spreadsheet`?

Comment: @waterloomatt yes both are same

Comment: @MonkeyZeus
@MonkeyZeus i think the `reader ` fail  because   
but when run it in server it looks like
`Xlsx {#1086 ▼
  -referenceHelper: ReferenceHelper {#191}
#readFilter: DefaultReadFilter {#1094}
  #securityScanner: XmlScanner {#1095 ▶}
}
`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the `reader` object should looks like
`PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx {#2244 ▼
  -referenceHelper: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\ReferenceHelper {#323}
  #readDataOnly: false
  #readEmptyCells: true
  #includeCharts: false
  #loadSheetsOnly: null
  #readFilter: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\DefaultReadFilter {#2281}
  #fileHandle: null
  #securityScanner: PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Security\XmlScanner {#2280 ▶}
}`

Comment: Okay, so comment out every line and uncomment them one by one until you find the failure.

Comment: Try Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel they have made working with excel super easy in Laravel.

Comment: may be the issue is because of file permissions on server the reader may not be able to access file as read-write mode